# python, Get values from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I have a complex structure of a list. like

`List-->dictionary-->list-->dictionary-->List-->Tuples`

How correctly can I get `['9142','9142','9143'...]` the values from this structure:

```
[{'row.0': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9141')]}}]},
 {'row.1': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9142')]}}]}, 
 {'row.2': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9143')]}}]}, 
 {'row.3': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9144')]}}]}, 
 {'row.4': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9146')]}}]}]
```

I want the output to have list like - `['9142','9142','9143'...]`

Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean "get" the values? What is your expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: you're asking the very basics. What about grabbing a book and opening it?

Comment: Thank you, I'm new in programming, so my question may be very simple for you!

Comment: @Suren Simonyan:  nice and complex structure of your list :) it will give tough time to get answer! :)

Comment: If this is a brain teaser from a textbook, you should tease your own brain. If this is a real world data structure, whoever came up with this should be taken out the back and shot.

Comment: @uwain12345 : agreed :D

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
s = [{'row.0': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9141')]}}]},
 {'row.1': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9142')]}}]}, 
 {'row.2': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9143')]}}]}, 
 {'row.3': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9144')]}}]}, 
 {'row.4': [{'item': {'props': [('col', 'CTO ID'), ('val', '9146')]}}]}]

res = []
for i in s:    #Iterate your list
    key, val = i.items()[0]  #get key, value
    res.append(val[0]['item']['props'][1][1])  #append your required value.
print res
```

**Output:**

```
['9141', '9142', '9143', '9144', '9146']
```

**Tested in python2.7**

Comment: Thank you Rakesh!